# What actually is java library files

Tags: java

Consider the programming language as Java.
What are library files?
Do library file contain code in High level language?
Are library files machine dependent?

I tried searching about it but then i got confused about these questions in different programming languages

Comment: Are you talking about `jar` files? Try to add some context.

Comment: Yes jar files are library files in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer this in familiar terms. I presume you have heard about classes, interfaces and packages in java. 
Libraries in java are essentially packages that contain classes or interfaces, which generally fall under a certain category. These classes or interfaces contain methods which you may be willing to use in your program without having to rewrite the whole method again. 
A common example can be the case where you want to get input from user. For this, you can use the Scanner class which contains various methods to take integer, string, character, etc input from the user. Now if you have gone through official Java Documentation of the Scanner class and how the methods you use are actually implemented you might want to refrain from re-implementing these methods yourself. So you usually import the Scanner class from an in-built Java package called `java.util`, this is what library actually is.
*A group of similar classes and/or interfaces which can be looked up, imported and used as required.*

---

**And most importantly, these are all written in the Java programming language.**

---

For more information you might want to lookup  [here:](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-Java-library-How-is-it-linked-with-our-program)

Answer (score 1):

A Java library contains code which you can access and use in your Java project. The deployment format of a Java library is a JAR file.

> A JAR file is a Java archive based on the pkzip file format. JAR files are the deployment format for Java. A JAR can contain Java classes and other resources (icons, property files, etc.) and can be executable.
>
> You can distribute your program in a jar file or you can use existing
>   java code via jars by putting them into your classpath.
>
> If you add a JAR file to your classpath, you can use its classes in
>   your Java application.

In Java, there are not machine dependent. Well, it's subjective. They run on Java's virtual machine which can be put on a lot of other machines.